# How to have a single class to extend to regular Activities and List Activities in Android

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity, listactivity

In my app I have common methods and attributes that I would like available to both List and regular activities.  I want to use inheritance to create a parent class to extend to both types of activities.  If I make the parent class extend list activity the regular activity will give me the exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Vica versa, I will not have the list functionality I need classes that extends this parent class.

How do I accomplish this without copying the same methods to two different classes that extend listactivity and activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use ListActivity unless you're looking for the simplest way to use a ListView.

The way I tackle this is chart out what activities I need, and what functionality I need across all of them, and only some, and `extend` accordingly.

For example, you can have you super-base activity, `BaseActivity`.  This can have setup, teardown, and whatever other functionality you need for all your child activities.  From there, you can have something like `BaseListActivity` that extends `BaseActivity`, handles everything you may need from `BaseActivity` and just add functionality for ListViews.

```
Activity > BaseActivity > BaseListActivity > MyListActivity
Activity > BaseActivity > MyPlainActivity
```

Here's a video of some classes I've been working on for managing Cursors as well as ListViews.

[ManagedActivity classes - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2Mxt_YuSjc&list=UUH4V9MOQFCb13u9MrYN5X0Q&index=1&feature=plcp)

Answer (score 0):

You are not obliged to have a ListActivity in order to have a ListView as a View inside your layout.

Based on this, you can make a BaseActivity that extends Activity, and add there all your methods and attributes.

Then all your Activities can extend this BaseActivity.

Hope this helps!